# How to properly call a function in deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Hi I'm having a web3 code, web3 version is 0.20.0

```
MyContract.addPerson.call("0x6b1c97bf430704e118cb3aaeb2bccce1a29d85e3",function (error, result){
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error:'+JSON.stringify(error));
                res.send({'status':0,'message':error});
            }else{
                console.log('Result:'+JSON.stringify(result));
                res.send({'status':1,'message':result});
            }
        });
```

My contract code is

```
function addPerson(address pesonAddress) public returns(address message){
        if(msg.sender != owner) {message = 0; revert();}
        if(auctioneers[pesonAddress] == true){
            message = 0;
        }else{
            auctioneers[pesonAddress] = true;
            auctionersList.push(pesonAddress);
            message = pesonAddress;
        }

    }
```

Compiler version is 0.4.20.

Also I tried with

```
MyContract.addPerson("0x25c8b176c11e21fe5ffdc943acdf6d070d197e02",{value:0,gas: 30000},function (error, result){
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error:'+JSON.stringify(error));
                res.send({'status':0,'message':error});
            }else{
                console.log('Result:'+JSON.stringify(result));
                res.send({'status':1,'message':result});
            }
        });
```

It shows `addPerson()` is not a function.

It works well when I test it in remix IDE. But when I call addPerson() with address as an parameter it doesn't add that address to the map and array.Also I checked the address by returning the address, it matches. Also I add an address in remix IDE and then I returned that array in web3js, it contains array of addresses that I added in remix IDE. What I'm doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: how do you create the contract instance?

Comment: Contract is working fine when I call other function. But not this addPerson()

Answer (score 1):

Calling your method in this way : `MyContract.addPerson.call(...)` is just a readonly interaction. And it is used to only return data, not update it.

In order to actually change storage ( add an item into an array or update a variable ) you need to call addPerson this way : `MyContract.addPerson(...)` without the `call`

Comment: Yes I also tested like that. In that case it shows addPerson() is not a function. I updated my question please look into it.

Comment: can you post the whole code  where you call the function in javascript

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Instead of call() what should I use read write interaction

Comment: you can use sendTransaction for functions who changes the state. But, in case you use `yourContract.method` web3 is able to define whether to use call or sendTransaction. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract